# Dictionary uses tostring instead of object?

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, adobe

Adobe [specifically states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) about Dictionaries:

> the object's identity is used to look up the object, and not the value returned from calling toString()

However when I run

```
if(myInstance in myDictionary)  { ... }
```

To see if myInstance already exists as a 'key' in myDictionary, myInstance.tostring get's called!

Anyone know why or a way around it?

Comment: What exactly do you want a workaround for? As far as I can see, the toString() method is called, but it is checked with identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` keyword is generally used with object properties, which are strings. Consider the difference between a `for each` loop versus a `for in` loop.

We typically use the `for in` loop to iterate over an object's dynamic properties:

```
private var o:Object = { property1: "value1", property2: "value2" };
for (var propertyName:String in o)
{
    trace(propertyName);
    trace(o[propertyName]);
}

Outputs:
property1
value1
property2
value2
```

So in your code snippet the `in` keyword is causing the call to `toString()`.

The correct way to test if a key exists is to test for `null`:

```
if (myDictionary[myInstance])
    trace("key exists and it has a value");
```

Comment: tnx! I get it now. The use of the 'in' keyword is just not appropriate here. if (myDictionary[myInstance]) is the way to go then.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft not sure what you mean. This is answering the question, where the OP was trying to use the following incorrect syntax: `if(myInstance in myDictionary)  { ... }` to see if a value existed in the `Dictionary`. Out of curiousity, and to be more helpful to others who visit this page, what is the part of my answer that you think is incorrect w/respect to the `in` keyword?

Comment: I mean, the syntax `if(myInstance in myDictionary) { ... }` is not incorrect.  It works correctly in AS3 for Dictionaries.  Try it: `var a:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
            var f:Object = {};
            var g:Object = {};
            a[f] = 100;
            if (f in a && !(g in a))
            {
                trace("Works correctly");
            }`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Wow, thanks for pointing that out! I had no idea you could use the `in` keyword that way (so used to only using it in for loops).